# Ember pikaday stored and displayed values

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I am trying to replace the ember-cli-datepicker with pikaday

```
        valueFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
        format="DD/MM/YYYY"
```

the value needs to be stored as YYYY-MM-DD -- but shown as DD/MM/YYYY. I've had to add an onSelect action to set the value -- but the display format is wrong.

```
{{pikaday-input
        value=localisedValue
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        useUTC=true
        name=name
        placeholder=localisedPlaceholder
        onSelection=(action (mut localisedValue))
        id=inputId
  classNames="date-placeholder"
  tabindex=tabIndex
}}
```

Comment: _"needs to be stored as YYYY-MM-DD"_ - where? in database?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DD/MM/YYYY` for the pikaday and a computed property for `localisedValue`, which mirrors the value as `YYYY-MM-DD` in another property.

```
_isoValue: '',
localisedValue: computed({
  get() {
    return moment(get(this, '_isoValue'), 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  },
  set(key, value) {
    set(this, '_isoValue', moment(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    return value;
  }
})
```

Comment: I am not sure where that would go - cause its nested quite deep in various partials - used for different types of forms etc.

Comment: I think I managed to get it working - just by changing the format to the display form - I think useUTC to true - satisfied the handler

Comment: You could create a component, which inherits from pikaday-input and adds custom logic, so that it's a one time addition. - But glad to hear, that you solved your case already with `useUTC`.